# activate knockout within constructor

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Instead of having to use `ko.applyBindings(new SomeClass());` to activate knocokout on a class, could I just use `ko.applyBindings(this);` within the constructor of `SomeClass`? I find it bad OOP in my opinion to have to apply it outside of the class. Wouldn't it be better to define in the class what it is supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `SomeClass` is the constructor for your overall view model and you are not going to create multiple instances of `SomeClass`, then you could call `ko.applyBindings` from within the constructor.

Calling `ko.applyBindings` multiple times on the same elements has some bad side-effects (multiple bindings + multiple event handlers attached), so you would want to be careful that you only call is once or call it passing different DOM elements to be the root as the second argument.

Comment: i tried it on the learn.knockoutjs.com site and it didn't work. could you show me a fiddle where it works?

Comment: Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/HAzyW/.  You do still need to create an instance of the type.